# Why aren't there pre-built PInvoke DLLs?

Tags: powershell, dll, pinvoke, unmanaged, managed

I am building a PowerShell script that uses a few user32.dll functions, and a few gdi32.dll functions. I've had to do this several times in the past.

I'm tired of looking at these huge blocks of C# code in a string in my PowerShell code. I am also tired of having to find the PInvoke code for each individual function I intend to use. I would like to have a single DLL that wraps all (known) user32.dll functions so that I can once and for all have them available to me.

I've googled around and don't seem to be able to find any prebuilt PInvoke wrapper DLLs for all known functions in user32.dll, win32.dll, or other popular unmanaged dlls. Why is this? I understand that perhaps they would not be stable and would constantly need updating - is that the reason?

I have also noticed that http://pinvoke.net/ provides a Visual Studio plugin that autogenerates signatures... does that mean that there is a pinvoke.net web service that I can use to automatically generate a dll based on the latest state of their database?

Comment: It sounds like something maybe [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) could take care of? But I know I wasn't satisfied with it in the case of Java, so I came up with my own tool named [JavaCPP](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp)...

Comment: You could write this yourself. What's stopping you? Auto generating based on pinvoke.net would be a bad idea because the content there is low quality.

Comment: I just found the web service: http://www.pinvoke.net/pinvokeservice.asmx so I think I will be writing it myself and posting it here soon. `function PInvoke($module){...}`

Comment: There're a lot of framework classes which are actually using p/invoke under the hood!

Comment: this is turning out to be very difficult, as many of the entries in pinvoke.net are designed to be interpreted by a human.

Comment: High proportions of the translations in pinvoke.net are plain wrong. There's no uniformity of style. Automated translations are invariably poor. Especially for this type of code, where the semantics of the interface is not found in its signature. You are pursuing a fool's errand.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan that's pretty much what i meant in my previous comment, and it's approaching being an answer to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason there are no pre-built DLLs on the Internet, and why no one uses PInvoke.net's web service to automate this, is that most of the data there is fine for a human to understand and interpret but not fine for consumption by an automated script. If it were cleaned up a ton, it might be possible however.

A lot of this information is still stored on msdn, but it would take time to create such wrapper DLLs that encompass all known functions. AFAIK, no one has done this yet. I would love to take the time to go through the 586 known functions in user32.dll and create a wrapper DLL that could be used by others, but I just don't have the time, as with most people who would do this I suppose. I assume Microsoft has not done this simply because they don't feel it would be worth their time.

In addition, it seems that some of these functions are built in such a way that may not even have a proper way to translate into managed code with certainty that they would work. In particular, interpreting which C# types should be used for C pointers seems to be an issue.

Comment: There's also plenty of things that could be meant by things like `char*` ... `string`, `StringBuilder`, `ref char`? Those things complicate automatic translation.

Answer (score 0):

One could easily use the P/Invoke web service you mentioned. I tried it and found, that the P/Invoke database is not at all well formed in a way that it can be imported with a script. It is **not** structured in a defined way, so you would either have to come up with some sort of "intelligent parsing" or fix the errors yourself, which would be way too much work! The kernel32.dll yields 4000 lines of code already, not to mention the hundreds of other libraries.

This is what I've done so far and the result, when put in a C# file, is not compilable. Filtering out the "TODO" items is one thing, but many items also contain syntax errors, refer to other structs that are not explicitly defined and so on... The problem simply is, that the database has no explicit format of any kind. It's all just plain text fields users can type text into.

I get 127 compile errors when using the result of the script below. This is the closest you can get, I think.

```
PInvokeServiceSoapClient client = new PInvokeServiceSoapClient();
client.Open();
foreach (FunctionInfo function in client.SearchFunction("kernel32.dll", new WikiVersion()))
{
    Console.WriteLine(function.Function);
    try
    {
        foreach (SignatureInfo signature in client.GetResultsForFunction(function.Function, function.Module))
        {
            if (signature.Language == "C#")
            {
                if (!signature.Signature.Contains("TODO"))
                {
                    if (!signature.Summary.StartsWith("TODO"))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("/// <summary>\r\n/// " + signature.Summary + "\r\n/// </summary>");
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine(signature.Signature.Replace("|", "\r\n"));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch { }
}
client.Close();
```

Maybe some day you come up with a creative idea on how to create a DLL that contains all WinAPI function and acts as a wrapper for everything. It would be cool!